# How to protect WinUI 3 app private key from another apps unauthorized access?

Tags: c#, winui-3, wincrypt

I'm developing a WinUI 3 app for Windows 11 in c#.

My app save encrypted data into a local database (data are encrypted by RSACryptoServiceProvider class).

The `RSACryptoServiceProvider` save the private and public keys into a container that other apps can read.
There are any ways to prevent unauthorized access to the keys from another apps ?